# Joomla3 Returns 404 Except on Front Page

Tags: joomla3.0

Migrated a site to a development server and am getting strange behavior.  No issue on the original box.  Did a manual move, i.e. scp'd files over to new box,  mysqldump of database on old box & restore database on new box and edited configuration.php file to point to new settings on dev box

I can hit the home page and all is well but for all menus I get a 404 error.  The config file shows url rewriting on and set on

```
public $sef = '1';
public $sef_rewrite = '1';
```

What is even stranger is that if I turn off sef most things work but not all.  For example I can call http://my.test.site/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=41&Itemid=116 and in the Apache access log I will get a 200 Response code but a blank page in the browser.

I have tried turning the set and rewrite settings on and off, clearing the cache and have been in the .htaccess file where I have toggled RewriteBase / on and off to no effect.

Anyone with ideas?

Dev Box - Apache 2.4.2 with PHP 5.5.3 and Joomla! 3.1.5 Stable [ Ember ]

Apache Modules Loaded via apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 cgid_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 geoip_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
 unique_id_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
```

Edit - I also have looked in my php and joomla logs and nothing comes up

Update - Made some progress.  Non sef URL's are all working.  Finally traced it to a missing module (images).  Still no progress on sef URL however.  All 404's on all other pages

Answer (score 0):

After going through a bunch of forums and emails my thoughts were the .htaccess file.  I went through many permutations but nothing seemed to help.

By accident I checked to see of mod_rewrite was loaded and functioning.  I was pretty sure it was loaded and it was but it was not working.  I did a test and could not get it to rewrite my URL's

e.g. I added this to my .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Redirect /cnn.html http://www.cnn.com
```

What I found was the in the Apache conf file the default install had AllowOverride None when it should have been AllowOverride All.  Once I made that change and restarted it was good to go